# R Function to split into new column on conditional data

Tags: r

I'm struggling to build a dataframe based on feedback/help I've received. Thus, I am reproducing my problem here:

```r
#Appointments.csv has about 4000 observations
library("data.table")
df <- fread("Appointments.csv",select=c("Subject","Customer","Employee","Meeting_Date","AM","Team"),header=TRUE)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df <- df %>% separate(Meeting_Date, c('Date', 'Time'), sep=" ")
df <- df %>% separate(Date, c('Month', 'Day', 'Year'), sep="/")

#Team is a cell that contains all team members and sometimes customer present in the meeting, up to 7.
df <- df %>% separate(Team, c('Spec1', 'Spec2', 'Spec3', 'Spec4', 'Spec5', 'Spec6, Spec7'), sep="; ")


team1 <- c('Paulo, Ted', 'Smith, Steve', 'Angel, Vanessa', 'Violet, Amy', 'Edwards, Emelio', 'Brown, Josh')
team2<-c('Collins, Heather', 'Davis, Catherine', 'Elliot, Jay', 'Goss, Ryan', 'Mayer, Wayne', 'Jones, Alexandra', 'Stevens, Jane', 'Price, Steve', 'Lane, Adam', 'Silvo, Dean', 'Wright, Barb', 'Smith, Liz', 'Telford, Chris')   
team3 <-c('Jolly, Nathan', 'Cooley, Greg', 'Miele, Michelle', 'Ogleby, Ozzy', 'Black, Kate')
team4 <-c('Clemente, Sam', 'Bosworth, Brian', 'Gay, Art', 'Patrick, Luke', 'Fitzsimmons, Zach', 'Hobbs, Kyle', 'Hamilton, August')
ees <- data.frame(Name = c(team1, team2, team3, team4))
```

1. Instead of separating team the way I am, I'd like to only add them into Spec1 - Spec7 if they are a member of ees (team 1-4).
2. I would like to add a column that counts the number of ees present in the appointment (i.e., adds the non-blank count of Spec1-Spec7).
3. I would like to summarize the number of meetings attended by team

I tried implementing suggestions, but I struggled with my understanding of "adding to" an existing dataframe.